# Ruby loop order?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to bruteforce a password. As I was playing with some loops, I've noticed there's a specific order. Like, if I have `for i in '.'..'~'` it puts

```
.
/
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
:
;
<
=
>
?
@
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
[
\
]
^
_
`
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
{
|
}
~
```

After seeing this, I wondered to myself "what is the loop order in Ruby?" What character is the highest priority and which is the lowest priority? Sorry if this question is basic. I just haven't found a site where anyone knows. If you have questions about the question just ask. I hope this is clear enough!

Comment: For your perusal: [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order is defined by the binary representation of the letters.  Which, in turn, is defined by a standard. The standard used is ASCII (American Standard Code for Information Interchange).

http://www.asciitable.com/

Other encoding standards exist, like EBCDIC which is used by IBM mid-range computers.

Comment: That makes so much sense! I know my ASCII table and I didn't even think of that. So, follow up question, the first value is \0. Could I start my loop with null? What would that even do?

Comment: You can't just use `nil` since that's a distinct object type, but you can create a string with a null value.  `null_value = [00].pack('c*')`  and then you can use `null_value` as the starting point of your ranges.  The characters that don't have displayable representations in ASCII will just show with the hex value, so a character with hex value of 1A (00011010) will print as "\x1A"

Answer (score 2):

[`for` / `in` is (mostly) syntactic sugar for `each`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000021), so

```
for i in '.'..'~' do puts i end
```

is (roughly) equivalent (modulo local variable scope) to

```
('.'..'~').each do |i| puts i end
```

Which means that we have to look at [`Range#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-each) for our answer (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## `each {| i | block }` → `rng`
>
> Iterates over the elements of range, passing each in turn to the block.
>
> The each method can only be used if **the begin object of the range supports the `succ` method**. A `TypeError` is raised if the object does not have `succ` method defined (like Float).

And [the documentation for the `Range` class itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#class-Range-label-Custom+Objects+in+Ranges) provides more details:

> ## Custom Objects in Ranges
>
> Ranges can be constructed using any objects that can be compared using the `<=>` operator. **Methods that treat the range as a sequence (`#each` and methods inherited from Enumerable) expect the begin object to implement a `succ` method to return the next object in sequence**.

So, while it isn't spelled out directly, it is clear that `Range#each` works by

1. Repeatedly sending the `succ` message to the *begin* object (and then to the object that was returned by `succ`, and then to *that* object, and so forth), and
2. Comparing the current element to the *end* object using the `<=>` spaceship combined comparison operator to figure out whether to produce another object or end the loop.

Which means that we have to look at [`String#succ`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-succ) next:

> ## `succ` → `new_str`
>
> Returns the successor to *str*. The successor is calculated by incrementing characters starting from the rightmost alphanumeric (or the rightmost character if there are no alphanumerics) in the string. Incrementing a digit always results in another digit, and incrementing a letter results in another letter of the same case. **Incrementing nonalphanumerics uses the underlying character set’s collating sequence**.

Basically, what this means is:

- incrementing a letter does what you expect
- incrementing a digit does what you expect
- incrementing something that is neither a letter nor a digit is arbitrary and dependent on the string's character set's [collating sequence](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation#Automated_collation)

In this particular case, you didn't tell us what the collating sequence of your string is, but I assume it is [ASCII](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), which means you get what is colloquially called [ASCIIbetical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_order).

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about priority, but the order of their values. As already said, the characters have their own **ASCII representation** (E.g., 'a' value is 97 and 'z' value is 122).

You could see this for yourself trying this:

```
('a'..'z').each do |c|
  puts c.ord
end
```

Analogously, this should also work:

```
(97..122).each do |i|
  puts i.chr
end
```